# What is a good source for learning fourier transformations as an application

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis

I'm an undergraduate physics major and for my research I need to start learning and understanding fourier transformations for my research. Does anyone know good resources for doing this. I don't need to understand the proofs and analysis of it (although it would help), I just need to understand the basics of it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this book](http://books.google.fr/books/about/The_Fourier_Transform_and_Its_Applicatio.html?id=ZNQQAQAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y) by Bracewell.